# Two teams work together and alone work problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When two teams A and B work together, it takes 18 days to complete a job. After team A works for 3 days, and Team B works for 4 days, only 1/5 of the job is done. How long does it take for Team A to complete the job alone? How long does it take for Team B to complete the job alone?

Whats the equation for the first sentence? I know the second one is
$3A+4B=1/5W$
when A is the speed of A, B is the speed of B, and W is the amount of work completed.

Comment: You probably shouldn't include W.  The amount of work is 1 job, let's keep it at 1 job.  $3A+4B=\frac{1}{5}$ and $18A+18B=1$ are your equations.

Comment: I just needed that $18A+18B=1$ equation. Thanks!

Comment: Now, you can answer your own question!  (yes really.  There's even a badge for it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I know...
$18A+18B=1$
$15A+20B=1$(multiplied by 5)

Substition, so it becomes
$18A+18B=15A+20B$
Then it becomes $3A=2B$, making B 1.5 times faster than A.
You can substitute B for 3 and A for 2 now. 
$54+36=90$, so $90/3=30$ days for B and $90/2=45$ days for A.

Comment: Nice.  I'd have picked $A = 2/90 = 1/45$ and $B = 3/90 = 1/30$, so there is really exactly 1 job's worth involved, and the result for each alone is obvious.